# How to programmatically Add a Process Template to TFS Collection

Tags: templates, collections, tfs, process

I want to add a new process template to a TFS 2012 collection programmatically or via command line. I have found great examples for updating project build templates but nothing for collections. Does anyone have any examples of how to do what I want?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it appears to be a request for someone else to write the code or explain how to write the code, and does not identify a specific problem or question about programming. Please include attempted solutions, an explanation of how the results differed from the expected results, and any error messages you received. Please read this: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to try, but this looks like the service that can do it for you:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://myserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection");
using (var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(uri))
{
    tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
    var server = tfs.GetService<Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.IProcessTemplates>();
    server.AddUpdateTemplate(name, description, metadata, state, zipFileName);
}
```

Full MSDN Documentation is here: [IProcessTemplates.AddUpdateTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.server.iprocesstemplates.addupdatetemplate.aspx)

*This is based off my [LinqPad template](http://taeguk.co.uk/blog/my-linqpad-tfs-template/) for TFS.

Comment: Thank you, This is just what I was just looking for the class/method as I was not successful in searching the TFS API in MSDN for answer.

Comment: @DCBarringer, no worries, would you mind checking if can you still accept an answer on a Closed question? Cheers.

Comment: I Yes I believe it worked.